# Slicing Pandas based on threshold and timestamp before and after

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
Timestamp (Index)       Status    value
2017-01-01 12:01:00     OPEN      83 
2017-01-01 12:02:00     OPEN      82 
2017-01-01 12:03:00     OPEN      87 
2017-01-01 12:04:00     CLOSE     82 
2017-01-01 12:05:00     CLOSE     81 
2017-01-01 12:06:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:07:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:08:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:09:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:10:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:11:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:12:00     OPEN      81
2017-01-01 12:13:00     OPEN      81
2017-01-01 12:14:00     OPEN      81
2017-01-01 12:15:00     OPEN      81
2017-01-01 12:16:00     CLEAR     34
2017-01-01 12:17:00     CLOSE     23
2017-01-01 12:18:00     CLOSE     23
2017-01-01 12:19:00     CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:20:00     CLOSE     65
2017-01-01 12:21:00     CLOSE     72
2017-01-01 12:22:00     CLOSE     76
2017-01-01 12:23:00     CLOSE     77
2017-01-01 12:24:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:25:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:26:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:27:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:28:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:29:00     CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:30:00     CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:31:00     CLOSE     75
```

In case the first of the consecutive CLOSE-values is below 70 I want to delete the OPEN-block that cames before and the CLOSE-block with the value below 70. It should look like this:

```
Timestamp (Index)       Status    value
2017-01-01 12:01:00     OPEN      83 
2017-01-01 12:02:00     OPEN      82 
2017-01-01 12:03:00     OPEN      87 
2017-01-01 12:04:00     CLOSE     82 
2017-01-01 12:05:00     CLOSE     81 
2017-01-01 12:06:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:07:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:08:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:09:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:10:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:11:00     CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:24:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:25:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:26:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:27:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:28:00     OPEN      87
2017-01-01 12:29:00     CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:30:00     CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:31:00     CLOSE     75
```

Any idea on how I can get hold of the relevant Timestamps in order to remove those periods?

Comment: What will the output for example in the case of one or more values in single consecutive close block are above 70 while other values are below 70? Or such case will never occur?

Comment: The output would be the same. Those cases do occur but I'm only interested in the first intervall that come after a close block...and then check on that condition.

Comment: Just to be clear if the close block contain `23 23 *72* 45 23 23 23`,  should the `close` rows after *72* will also get deleted, or we don't have to consider such kind of interval?

Comment: I changed my values slightly. The entire close block should be deleted in case the first close value is below 70. Also, there might be a clwar intervall in bettween. That can be removed as well. Basically I need a way to access the timestamps of the first open and last close intervall and then remove that block....

Comment: I think answer given by @ipj should work for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.groupby((df.status.shift().bfill().ne(df.status) & df.status.eq('OPEN')).cumsum()).transform(min).value.ge(70)]
```

result:

```
                    status  value
timestamp                        
2017-01-01 12:01:00   OPEN     83
2017-01-01 12:02:00   OPEN     82
2017-01-01 12:03:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:04:00  CLOSE     82
2017-01-01 12:05:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:06:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:07:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:08:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:09:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:10:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:11:00  CLOSE     81
2017-01-01 12:24:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:25:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:26:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:27:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:28:00   OPEN     87
2017-01-01 12:29:00  CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:30:00  CLOSE     75
2017-01-01 12:31:00  CLOSE     75
```

The method is to create groups where `status` is not equal to previous `status`, begining with `status == 'OPEN'`.

Then preserving rows where `value` is greater or equal 70 per group.

Comment: Good to hear it :-) If it's ok, consisder accepting solution as an answer please.